# Is it possible to split a file content after every 6. row with the `split` function?

Tags: perl, text, split

Is it possible to split a file content after every 6. row with the `split` function?

I tried different patterns without success.
The last one:

```
split /(?=(?:.+$){6})/, $content;
```

In this example every 3. line:

the content of the file:

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

the result after the split:

```
a1
a2
a3,

b1
b2
b3,

c1
c2
c3
```

Comment: As it stands, this question is quite unclear. I would help if you could provide some sample data, the corresponding expected result, and maybe a little more of your existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the question is about how to split a multiline string into 6-lines substrings, then using a zero-width look-ahead regex as in the question

```
/(?=(?:.+$){6})/m
```

(note that in the question the `m` modifier was missing) cannot work since it will match at each end-of-line (`$`) (provided there are more than six lines to follow) and hence will split the string at each line. What we need is a regex that consumes the lines (not a zero-width assertion). We can achieve that by using

```
/(?:^[^\n]+\n){6}/m
```

as the separator regex in `split` and also make split return the separators by putting the regex in parenthesis. Now, split will interleave the separators with the strings that is between the separators (which in this case will be empty strings (since the separators follow each other with no characters between). To get rid of the empty strings with use `grep`:

```
my @res = grep {length} split /((?:^[^\n]+\n){6})/m, $content;
```

Comment: Could you add some description as to why this works

Comment: Thanks, I can understand that now :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't go with a regex in the situation you've explained. Instead, just look at the number of lines you've read and output whatever you like when you've read the right number of lines:

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    if( $. % 3 ) {  # $. is the line number for that filehandle
        print;
        }
    else {
        chomp;
        print $_, ",\n\n";
        }
    }

__DATA__
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

If you have your contents in a scalar in the program, you can open a file handle on that scalar so you can use the same file reading tools:

```
open my $string_fh, '<', \$content;

while( <$string_fh> ) {
    if( $. % 3 ) {  # $. is the line number for that filehandle
        print;
        }
    else {
        chomp;
        print $_, ",\n\n";
        }
    }
```

Turning things into file reading problems is one of my favorite tricks and I show many more ways to do this sort of thing in [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com). For example, if you wanted to also write to a string instead of standard output, you could open a file handle on a scalar reference:

```
open my $string_fh, '<', \$content;
open my $out_fh, '>', \(my $out);

while( <$string_fh> ) {
    if( $. % 3 ) {  # $. is the line number for that filehandle
        print {$out_fh} $_
        }
    else {
        chomp;
        print {$out_fh} $_, ",\n\n";
        }
    }

print $out;
```

This makes it easy to switch back and forth from capturing the info in a string or writing to a "real" filehandle.

Comment: I can see your point. The reason for the `split` approach is that I used [App::DBBrowser](https://metacpan.org/release/App-DBBrowser) to insert a table in a database. After copying the table from a PDF file all cells where in its own row. Now with the regex from the accepted answer (with an inlined modifier `((?m)(?:^[^\n]+\n){6})`) separating the records works fine. To remove the empty lines i used the 'Row_Groups' filter.